Is it possible to activate second or third notebook page instead of the first one, based on some conditions?
Is it possible to activate second or third notebook page instead of the first one, based on some conditions?
For example, If boolean field A is checked then activate or focus on second page and if boolean field B is checked then activate of focus third page of the notebook.
See attached screenshot

I want to activate second page by default in odoo notebooks pages.

AFAIK that's not possible with Odoo standard code/framework.

Yes, it is possible to programmatically activate or focus on different notebook pages based on conditions such as the state of a boolean field. In JavaScript frameworks like React or even plain HTML with JavaScript, you can control tabbed navigation by checking conditions and dynamically setting the active tab.
For example, if you're using React with state management, you could have code like this:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TabbedPage = () => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(1); // Start with the first tab active
  const [isCheckedA, setIsCheckedA] = useState(false);
  const [isCheckedB, setIsCheckedB] = useState(false);

  // Check conditions and set the active tab accordingly
  const handleTabChange = () => {
    if (isCheckedA) {
      setActiveTab(2); // Activate second page
    } else if (isCheckedB) {
      setActiveTab(3); // Activate third page
    } else {
      setActiveTab(1); // Default to first page
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {/* The checkboxes to trigger conditions */}
      <div>
        <label>
          Field A:
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => setIsCheckedA(!isCheckedA)} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Field B:
          <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => setIsCheckedB(!isCheckedB)} />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleTabChange}>Check Conditions and Switch Tabs</button>
      </div>

      {/* Tab navigation */}
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li className={activeTab === 1 ? 'active' : ''}>Closing Match</li>
          <li className={activeTab === 2 ? 'active' : ''}>Travel & Prepare</li>
          <li className={activeTab === 3 ? 'active' : ''}>Arrival, Stay & Return</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      {/* Tab content */}
      <div>
        {activeTab === 1 && <div>Content for Closing Match</div>}
        {activeTab === 2 && <div>Content for Travel & Prepare</div>}
        {activeTab === 3 && <div>Content for Arrival, Stay & Return</div>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TabbedPage;

In this example:

activeTab controls which tab is currently displayed.
isCheckedA and isCheckedB are tied to the checkboxes, and their states determine which tab should be active.
The handleTabChange function checks the conditions and activates the corresponding tab.

If you are working with a web framework other than React, similar logic can be applied using vanilla JavaScript with document.querySelector() and event listeners for click or change events.
